# Change ajax url with parameter from previous jquery mobile page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I am building an app using JQM 1.0.1. I have a query that outputs to JSON a list of cities and how many shops are in each city for a particular type of shop. I have several shop types: Mechanical, tires, paint and body, etc. I have a different query for each shop type. On the first page of my mobile app, I have a list of the different shop types and on the shoptype page, I use ajax to make a list of the cities and the count of shops for each city. I would like to change the ajax url by passing a parameter from the list of each shop type on the first page. This way I could dynamically load the correct query instead of having multiple pages for this.

query example:

```
$query= "SELECT City, COUNT(ShopId) AS count FROM tabel WHERE Shoptype = 'D' and Visible = 1 Group By `City`";
```

First page:

```
<div data-role="page" id="shopType" data-add-back-btn="true">
<div data-role="header" class="heading">
    <h1></h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
 <div class="choiceList">
        <h1>Choose a shop type</h1>
 </div> 
    <ul data-role="listview" class="mainmenu">
        <li><a href="#shopType.html" id="diesel" data-transition="slide">Diesel Repair</a></li>
        <li><a href="shopType.html"  data-transition="slide">Mechanical</a></li>
        <li><a href="shopType.html" data-transition="slide">Paint and Body</a></li>
        <li><a href="shopType.html" data-transition="slide">Tires</a></li>
        <li><a href="shopType.html" data-transition="slide">Transmission</a></li>
    </ul>       
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
    <h4><script type="text/javascript">
    var d = new Date();
    document.write('<span class="copyright">© ' + d.getFullYear() + ' </span>');
    </script> </h4>
</div>
```

Second page (shopType.html)

```
<div id="city" data-role="page"  data-add-back-btn="true">
<div data-role="header"></div>

<div data-role="content">
<div class="choiceList">
<ul data-role="listview" id="cityMenu" class="mainmenu"></ul>

<script>
    jQuery(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/typeD.php',
            processData: true,
            data:{},
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(json) {
                $.each(json.shops, function(i, dat){
                    var count = dat.count;
                    var city = dat.City;
                    $("#cityMenu").append('<li><a href="#">' + city + '<span class="ui-li-count">' + count + '</span></a></li>');
                });
                $("#cityMenu").listview("refresh");
            },
            error: function(x,y,z) {}
        });
    });

</script>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Make a `url` variable and substitute that in for your static url?

Comment: Hint: JQM 1.0 is way old, upgrade to latest version 1.4.3